# URL Rewriting-Page display - rewrite rule in .htaccess

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, rule

For URL Rewriting, i have got the output for static URL
But , for dynamic URL , i am getting partial output only.
I have placed the .htaccess file in the root directory only.
Here is the code:

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^booking/price/([0-9]+)/?$ booking.php?price=$1

What will be the solution ?

Comment: What is the problem? What do you mean by partial output?

Comment: You need to give an example of your url input and what you would expect as output for us to help you get it right.

Comment: @Vithya what did you rollback to the original version for? Gumbo fixed your post.

Comment: Existing URL is : http://example.com/booking.php?price=40&pass=4
I need to rewrite as : http://example.com/booking/40/4

Comment: By mistake i hit the rollback.
I need to retrieve it.

Comment: Partial output means- no images,CSS files , functionality is displayed.
Part of pages are displaying here and there

Answer (score 1):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^booking/([0-9]+)/?$ booking.php?price=$1
RewriteRule ^booking/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ booking.php?price=$1&pass=$2
```

You really want to customise your code for these though so as to be able to use general rules, rather than converting specific paths to use $_GET.

Comment: Thank U.
I used this code.
Its rewriting.But,even some  CSS Issues , images display here and there occuring.
What to do?
If the same URL is not redirected, i mean using query strings, passing values, no CSS issues ocur.
Everything work fine there.
But if use this URL rewrite, this issue occuring,though i placed the .htaccess file in the root directory

Comment: I suspect that's happening because your CSS & images are being included with relative urls rather than absolutely - so it might be trying to get a css file from /booking/5454/style.css rather than /style.css.

Comment: Ya ...I tried that.If i give the full site URL in the src attribute, its displaying everything correctly.
Is there any other rule for this ?

Comment: If i give "http://example.com/inc/style.css" in the src tag of my page, everything displaying perfectly
Is there any rule for this??

Comment: How can i use the rewrite base rule

Answer (score -1):

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^booking/([0-9]+)/?$ booking.php?price=$1
RewriteRule ^booking/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ booking.php?price=$1&pass=$2

For images and Css you need to define your base folder in htaccess file as
 RewriteBase /~your folder/